Can I run Apache Ignite server node and client node in different webapps in same Tomcat instance?
I have a requirement where One webapp let's say 'webapp1' will host the Ignite server cluster, and webapp2 acts as client node using ignite webSessionFilter for session replication use case.
How to achieve this?
I do not want to start two different ignite clusters in two webapps.

Let's discuss some terminology first. 1.) The term "cluster" implies that there is more than 1 Ignite server instance involved. If you do not have more than 1 Ignite server instance, then you do not have a cluster you have an Ignite node or server. 2.) You mention that you have a session replication use case. Anytime replication is discussed for durability purposes there should be more than 1 Ignite instance involved and furthermore these 2 Ignite instances should reside on different physical hosts. If they do not, well you can have replication on the same host, but you do not have reliability nor durability. Given the above it seems that running 2 Ignite instances on 2 hosts would be your best option! And BTW that is the beauty of Ignite. You can have multiple hosts and the data can be both spread out on multiple hosts for performance purposes and replicated for durability purposes. Net / net is you get the best of both worlds. Hope that helps!

I think I am able to achieve what I was looking for.
My application is hosted in Tomcat web server. There are two webapps running there.
One webapp starts the server node, another webapp starts the client node. The client node consumes the cache through WebSessionFilter for session caching
